# does Haskell support MongoDB's query operators such as "$in"?

Tags: haskell, mongodb-query

To retrieve a set of documents whose certain field such as author is any one of a set of values, how does haskell's mongodb do that? as it is not apparent to me.
Thanks for any hint and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [mongoDB](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mongoDB) package, then notice that it accepts arbitrary document as a [Selector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mongoDB-1.4.1.1/docs/Database-MongoDB-Query.html#t%3aSelector). So you are free to use anything `mongodb` supports, including `$in`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}

import Database.MongoDB
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

main = do
  pipe <- runIOE $ connect $ host "127.0.0.1"
  e <- access pipe master "testdb" $ do
    insertMany "test" [
      ["i" =: 1, "name" =: "Name1"],
      ["i" =: 2, "name" =: "Name2"],
      ["i" =: 3, "name" =: "Name3"]
      ]
    rest =<< find (select ["i" =: ["$in" =: [1, 3]]] "test")
  close pipe
  print e
```

Output:

```
Right [[ _id: 52a9ea3008d0cf401e000000, i: 1, name: "Name1"],[ _id: 52a9ea3008d0cf401e000002, i: 3, name: "Name3"]]
```

Happy hacking with haskell and mongodb :)